# RuntimeError: input(): lost sys.stdin

Tags: python, pyinstaller

Написал простой код на Python.

```
name = input("Имя: ")

print(name)
```

Сохранил, решил преобразовать его в .exe через pyinstaller:

```
pyinstaller -w --onefile УказалПутьКФайлу.py
```

Файл вроде бы преобразовался и появился в папке dist, но при его запуске появляется следующее:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "example.py" line 1, in <module>

RuntimeError: input(): lost sys.stdin
```

Answer (score 0):

Уберите ключ -w, без него работает. Что он значит, в доке не смотрел :)